# Laravel: Sentry permissions not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I have got the following in my sentry seeder:

```
<?php

use App\Models\User;

class SentrySeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();
        DB::table('groups')->delete();
        DB::table('users_groups')->delete();

        Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
            'email'       => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password'    => "admin@admin.com",
            'first_name'  => 'Kamran',
            'last_name'   => 'Ahmed',
            'activated'   => 1,
        ));

        Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
            'email'       => 'user@user.com',
            'password'    => "user@user.com",
            'first_name'  => 'New',
            'last_name'   => 'User',
            'activated'   => 1,
        ));

        Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
            'name'        => 'Admin',
            'permissions' => array(
                'blog' => 1
            ),
        ));

        Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
            'name'        => 'Blogger',
            'permissions' => array(
                'blog.add' => 1,
                'blog.update' => 1,
                'blog.trash' => 1,
                'blog.remove' => 1
            ),
        ));

        // Assign user permissions
        $adminUser  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('admin@admin.com');
        $adminGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Admin');

        $normalUser  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('user@user.com');
        $normalGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Blogger');

        $adminUser->addGroup($adminGroup);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have defined two groups `Admin` and `Blogger`. `Admin` has all the permissions defined by `blog`, while blogger can only `blog.add`, `blog.update`, `blog.trash` and `blog.remove`. In my post view, I have got a button called `Delete Permanently` for which I have used the permission `blog.remove`. I want to show this button only if `Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess(array('blog', 'blog.remove'))`:

```
@if (Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess(array('blog', 'blog.remove')))
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{URL::to('post/delete/' . $post->id)}}">Delete Permanently</a>
@endif
```

Now when I login using the `admin@admin.com`, it works fine that is remove button is shown as expected, because the `admin` has the access to `blog` permission. But, when I login using `user@user.com`, the button is not being shown. What is the reason that the button is not being shown although I have assigned the permission of `blog.remove` to `user@user.com`. Also I did a `var_dump(..)` and it's return `false`. Can any one please tell me what's wrong with my implementation? Why is the removal button not being shown for the `user@user.com` user?

Comment: looking at your seeder, your only adding a user into the admin group, not the blogger group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your seeder your not assigning the user to the `blogger` group.

```
$normalUser->addGroup($normalGroup);
```